# Wanting to add a bool subscript to SKSpriteNode in swift so that I can toggle it on and off?

Tags: swift, class, skspritenode, subscript

I'm wanting to be able to toggle on and off a bool var (isActive) on a SKSpriteNode.

for example.

```
 someNode.isActive.toggle()
```

I'm sure its simple but for some reason it is escaping me right now.
I'm having a brain fart, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It finally came to me.

```
    protocol Active {
         var isActive: Bool { get set }
    }

    extension SKSpriteNode: Active {
         var isActive: Bool {
             get {
                 return false
             }
             set {}
         }
     }
```